# json_decode value math's in loop

Tags: php, foreach, syntax

I have a loop which process a `JSON` string via `json_decode`.

I am trying to perform some math calculations on a value before I pass it to my table. At the moment I can echo the desired output inside the loop using `echo $mileage1.";";` but I need to change the key `lc` to the division of `1000`.

There must be a way to do it inside the `foreach` statement, not in the block: something like `foreach(json_decode($url2, true)['status'] ($status["lc"] / 1000) as $status)` for example where `($status["lc"] / 1000)` does the math outside the loop block.

I haven't been able to find any examples of this specific situation so far.
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Here is a snipplet of my code:

```
$ret_array = array();
$url2 = file_get_contents("http://URLApi?");
foreach(json_decode($url2, true)['status'] as $status){
//mileage maths??
$mileage = $status["lc"];
$mileage1 = ($mileage) / 1000;
//echo $mileage1.";";
$ret_array[] = $status;
}
return $ret_array;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three options to replace the value in the array with the calculated value in a `foreach`:

First, reference `&` the value to change it in the original array:

```
$array = json_decode($url2, true);

foreach($array['status'] as &$status){
    $status["lc"] = $status["lc"] / 1000;
}
```

Second, modify the original array using the key:

```
$array = json_decode($url2, true);

foreach($array['status'] as $key => $status){
    $array['status'][$key]["lc"] = $status["lc"] / 1000;
}
```

Third, create a new result array:

```
foreach(json_decode($url2, true)['status'] as $status){
    $status["lc"] = $status["lc"] / 1000;
    $result[] = $status;
}

// Or if you need to preserve keys:

foreach(json_decode($url2, true)['status'] as $key => $status){
    $status["lc"] = $status["lc"] / 1000;
    $result[$key] = $status;
}
```

You could also map each element to a function that does the calculation:

```
$result = array_map(function($v) { return $v['lc'] = $v['lc'] / 1000; },
                    json_decode($url2, true)['status']);
```